# Where can I find __enter__() and __close__() for pytest.raises() expression?

Tags: exception, pytest, contextmanager

As the title says. When I run for instance

```
with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError) as error:
    division(1, 0)
```

where can I find the `__enter__()` and `___exit__()` methods run in the context manager when `pytest.raises` is called?

Comment: Do you mean In the `pytest` source code? Maybe I don't understand the question. What do you actually want to do? Also, do you mean `__enter__` and `__exit__`?

Comment: What I mean is that I would like to understand what actually happens when ```pytest.raises``` is executed in a context manager. Yes, I meant ```__exit__``` not ```__close__```. I corrected this in my initial post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does pytest.raises(Error) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34979138/how-does-pytest-raiseserror-work). Also, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/reference.html#pytest-raises) and the [source code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/4.6.x/_modules/_pytest/python_api.html#raises).